# How to get the particular member from objects dynamic view in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the total count of holes from sheet metal document of solid edge by c#.
I have my data in objects dynamic view.
Like

```
SheetMetalDocument.models.item(1).features.parent;
```

In parents dynamic view I have my data called holegeometries how to get this?

```
SheetMetalDocument.models.item(1).features.parent.getType(). getproperties().getValue("Holegeometries");
```

But this returning null..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.